# Using Phonegap Barcode Scanner on Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm trying to add a [barcode scanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner) to a JQM phonegap project for iOS.  I have followed the instructions listed, although I'm not 100% sure if I did the first and last steps correctly.

> Copy the .h, .cpp and .mm files to the Plugins directory in your
>   project. You may need to set the compile options for
>   zxing-all-in-one.cc to turn off optimization.

I directly copied the three files into the plugins folder in xcode.  It isn't giving me any errors, but it also isn't working.  I have no idea how to do compiler options in xcode, so I haven't done the last step.

Currently my app still runs with no errors and running the scan function opens the camera with the ui for the barcode scanner up.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to be either looking for or finding barcodes, it just stays up and does nothing (until you hit cancel, then it displays the cancelled message correctly).

Anyone have any ideas what's wrong or where I should look?

Comment: can you please help me in this, i am struggling to get it working, at the moment i am getting an error. "error in success callback: networkstatus0= typeerror: 'null' is not an object".

Comment: Err, although that doesn't really have anything to do with my question I'll try to help anyway... that error normally comes from you having an object that is null (getting a return parameter from the callback as null but then trying to parameter.WasSuccessful() or something).  I'd try just printing out any objects you are using and seeing if any are null that shouldn't be.  If that doesn't work I'd post a question instead of commenting in an unrelated 5 month old resolved question.

Comment: Thanks for heads up, One of the moderater deallocated my account, so i cant post questions, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the camera is turned on and the UI for scanning appears on the screen, then it means you've done everything right. The problem seems to be that the scanner doesn't detect the barcodes.

Be aware that recognizing 1D barcodes ("classical" barcodes) with zxing require an iPhone with  autofocus lens (iPhone 4 or iPhone 4S). 1D barcodes are a little tricky to detect with mobile phone lenses, you need proper light and focus ; that's one reason why 2D codes like QR code where invented.

Try generating a QR code with http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/, display it on the screen and try scanning it with your app. If it works then good news, everything is OK, but bad news, your phone is not fit for 1D barcode scanning.

Comment: Well, that might explain it because we're using an Ipod Touch for testing right now.  I believe we did try a QR code when we were trying to get something to scan, but I can try again and see if someone with a newer iPhone will volunteer for testing.  I'll let you know if that was the problem.

Comment: We tried it with another employee's Iphone 4 and it worked.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation for this behaviour are compiler flags. As mentioned on [BarcodeScanner wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner), you *may need to set the compile options for zxing-all-in-one.cc to turn off optimization.*

In XCode4, click on your project, then select your target under *Targets*, go to *Build Phases->Compile Sources*, select *zxing-all-in-one.cc* and enter *-O0* (that's dash oh naught) into the *Compiler flags* column.

That solved it for me.